# Module '"redux"' has no exported member 'combineReducers'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
});
export default rootReducer;`enter code here`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a folder called "redux" with an "index.js" in your application? If so, please rename that folder.

Generally, you can find a recommended example file structure in [the Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#structure-files-as-feature-folders-with-single-file-logic)

Comment: This plagued me for months a few years back. The correct fix for my situation was to modify my webpack config on the order of how it resolved modules